# handling close window and change button color

Tags: python, button, graphics, click, drawing

Alright I have updated my code, now , the only thing I am having problem with is, I want to close the window when the user clicks "911" and I tried using while loop, but the thing is I could not think of a good way to get 911 buttons to = win.close, and the other problem is, I want to change the button color of the last button that the user clicked, I changed one of the buttons color when I click on on it, but if I click another button the previous button won't turn back to the main color:S anything that can helps with my problem??

```
   # button.py
 from graphics import *

 from dieview import DieView
 from button import Button



 win = GraphWin("Phone", 160,160)
 win.setBackground("gray")

 m = Button (win, Point(30,20),10,10,"1")
 quitButton= Button(win, Point(60,20), 10, 10, "2")
 quitButton.label.setFill('black')
 quitButton.rect.setWidth(1)
 quitButton.active=True
 quitButton1 = Button(win, Point(30,20), 10, 10, "1")
 quitButton1.label.setFill('black')
 quitButton1.rect.setWidth(1)
 quitButton1.active=True
 quitButton2 = Button(win, Point(90,20), 10, 10, "3")
 quitButton2.label.setFill('black')
 quitButton2.rect.setWidth(1)
 quitButton2.active=True
 quitButton3 = Button(win, Point(30,50), 10, 10, "4")
 quitButton3.label.setFill('black')
 quitButton3.rect.setWidth(1)
 quitButton3.active = True
 quitButton4 = Button(win, Point(60,50), 10, 10, "5")
 quitButton4.label.setFill('black')
 quitButton4.rect.setWidth(1)
 quitButton4.active=True
 quitButton5 = Button(win, Point(90,50), 10, 10, "6")
 quitButton5.label.setFill('black')
 quitButton5.rect.setWidth(1)
 quitButton5.active=True
 quitButton6 = Button(win, Point(30,80), 10, 10, "7")
 quitButton6.label.setFill('black')
 quitButton6.rect.setWidth(1)
 quitButton6.active=True
 quitButton7 = Button(win, Point(60,80), 10, 10, "8")
 quitButton7.label.setFill('black')
 quitButton7.rect.setWidth(1)
 quitButton7.active=True
 quitButton8 = Button(win, Point(90,80), 10, 10, "9")
 quitButton8.label.setFill('black')
 quitButton8.rect.setWidth(1)
 quitButton8.active=True
 quitButton0 = Button(win,Point(90,110),20,10,"quit")
 quitButton0.label.setFill("red")
 quitButton0.rect.setWidth(1)
 quitButton0.active=True
 q=Circle(Point(90,110),10)
 q.setFill("gray")
 q.draw(win)
 Text(Point(90,110),"quit").draw(win)
 value=DieView(win,Point(30,20),10)
 value8=DieView(win,Point(90,80),10)
 c = Circle(Point(30,20),10)
 c.setFill("lightgray")
 c.draw(win)
 Text(Point(30,20), "1").draw(win)
 c1 = Circle(Point(60,20),10)
 c1.setFill("lightgray")
 c1.draw(win)
 Text(Point(60,20), "2").draw(win)
 c2 = Circle(Point(90,20),10)
 c2.setFill("lightgray")
 c2.draw(win)
 Text(Point(90,20),"3").draw(win)
 c3 = Circle(Point(30,50),10)
 c3.setFill("lightgray")
 c3.draw(win)
 c4 = Circle(Point(60,50),10)
 c4.setFill("lightgray")
 c4.draw(win)
 Text(Point(30,50), "4").draw(win)
 c5 = Circle(Point(90,50),10)
 c5.setFill("lightgray")
 c5.draw(win)
 Text(Point(60,50), "5").draw(win)
 c6 = Circle(Point(30,80),10)
 c6.setFill("lightgray")
 c6.draw(win)
 Text(Point(90,50), "6").draw(win)
 c7 = Circle(Point(60,80),10)
 c7.setFill("lightgray")
 c7.draw(win)
 Text(Point(30,80), "7").draw(win)
 c8 = Circle(Point(90,80),10)
 c8.setFill("lightgray")
 c8.draw(win)
 Text(Point(60,80), "8").draw(win)
 Text(Point(90,80), "9").draw(win)
 listclick=[quitButton,quitButton1]

 pt = win.getMouse()
 while not quitButton0.clicked(pt):
     if quitButton.clicked(pt):
         print("2")
         c1.setFill("red")

     elif quitButton1.clicked(pt):
         print("1")
     elif quitButton2.clicked(pt):
         quitButton.active=True
         print("3")
     elif quitButton3.clicked(pt):
         quitButton3.active = True
         print("4")
     elif quitButton4.clicked(pt):
         quitButton4.active = True
         print("5")
     elif quitButton5.clicked(pt):
         quitButton5.active = True
         print("6")
     elif quitButton6.clicked(pt):
         quitButton6.active = True
         print("7")
     elif quitButton7.clicked(pt):
         quitButton7.active = True
         print("8")
     elif quitButton8.clicked(pt):
         quitButton8.active=True
         print("9")
     pt = win.getMouse()
 quitButton0=win.close()
```

Comment: you should use `bind` (google `bind TK`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

:s it took so long and no one answered my question, so I already figured it out
# button.py
from graphics import *

```
 from button import Button



 win = GraphWin("Phone", 140,160)
 win.setBackground("lightgray")
 quitButton0 =Button(win,Point(60,110),18,10,"0")
 quitButton0.label.setFill("black")
 quitButton0.rect.setWidth(1)
 quitButton0.active=True
 quitButton= Button(win, Point(60,20), 18, 10, "2")
 quitButton.label.setFill('black')

 quitButton.rect.setWidth(1)
 quitButton.active=True
 quitButton1 = Button(win, Point(30,20), 18, 10, "1")
 quitButton1.label.setFill('black')
 quitButton1.rect.setWidth(1)
 quitButton1.active=True
 quitButton2 = Button(win, Point(90,20), 18, 10, "3")
 quitButton2.label.setFill('black')
 quitButton2.rect.setWidth(1)
 quitButton2.active=True
 quitButton3 = Button(win, Point(30,50), 18, 10, "4")
 quitButton3.label.setFill('black')
 quitButton3.rect.setWidth(1)
 quitButton3.active = True
 quitButton4 = Button(win, Point(60,50), 18, 10, "5")
 quitButton4.label.setFill('black')
 quitButton4.rect.setWidth(1)
 quitButton4.active=True
 quitButton5 = Button(win, Point(90,50), 18, 10, "6")
 quitButton5.label.setFill('black')
 quitButton5.rect.setWidth(1)
 quitButton5.active=True
 quitButton6 = Button(win, Point(30,80), 18, 10, "7")
 quitButton6.label.setFill('black')
 quitButton6.rect.setWidth(1)
 quitButton6.active=True
 quitButton7 = Button(win, Point(60,80), 18, 10, "8")
 quitButton7.label.setFill('black')
 quitButton7.rect.setWidth(1)
 quitButton7.active=True
 quitButton8 = Button(win, Point(90,80), 18, 10, "9")
 quitButton8.label.setFill('black')
 quitButton8.rect.setWidth(1)
 quitButton8.active=True
 quitButton13 = Button(win, Point(90,200), 0, 0, "")
 quitButton13.label.setFill('gray')
 quitButton13.rect.setWidth(0)
 quitButton13.active=False


 c0=Circle(Point(60,110),10)
 c0.setFill("gray")
 c0.draw(win)
 Text(Point(60,110),"0").draw(win)
 c1 = Circle(Point(60,20),10)
 c1.setFill("gray")
 c1.draw(win)
 Text(Point(60,20), "2").draw(win)
 c2 = Circle(Point(90,20),10)
 c2.setFill("gray")
 c2.draw(win)
 Text(Point(90,20),"3").draw(win)
 c3 = Circle(Point(30,50),10)
 c3.setFill("gray")
 c3.draw(win)
 c4 = Circle(Point(60,50),10)
 c4.setFill("gray")
 c4.draw(win)
 Text(Point(30,50), "4").draw(win)
 c5 = Circle(Point(90,50),10)
 c5.setFill("gray")
 c5.draw(win)
 Text(Point(60,50), "5").draw(win)
 c6 = Circle(Point(30,80),10)
 c6.setFill("gray")
 c6.draw(win)
 Text(Point(90,50), "6").draw(win)
 c7 = Circle(Point(60,80),10)
 c7.setFill("gray")
 c7.draw(win)
 Text(Point(30,80), "7").draw(win)
 c8 = Circle(Point(90,80),10)
 c8.setFill("gray")
 c8.draw(win)
 Text(Point(60,80), "8").draw(win)
 Text(Point(90,80), "9").draw(win)
 close = Button(win, Point(30,20), 10, 10, "1")
 close.label.setFill("black")
 close.rect.setWidth(0)
 close.active=False
 Text(Point(30,20), "1").draw(win)
 but=Button(win,Point(30,20),10,10,"1")
 but.label.setFill("black")
 but.rect.setWidth(0)
 #but.active = False
 h = Circle(Point(30,20),10)
 h.setFill("gray")
 h.draw(win)
 Text(Point(30,20), "1").draw(win)
 pt = win.getMouse()

 while not but.clicked(pt):


    if quitButton8.clicked(pt):
         quitButton8.active=True
         print("9")
         c8.setFill("red")
         close.active=True
         c0.setFill("gray")
         quitButton1.active=False
         c1.setFill("gray")
         c2.setFill("gray")
         c3.setFill("gray")
         c4.setFill("gray")
         c5.setFill("gray")
         c6.setFill("gray")
         c7.setFill("gray")
         h.setFill("gray")
    
     elif close.clicked(pt):
         close.active=False
         h.setFill("red")
         print("1")
         but.active=True
         c1.setFill("gray")
         c2.setFill("gray")
         c3.setFill("gray")
         c4.setFill("gray")
         c5.setFill("gray")
         c6.setFill("gray")
         c7.setFill("gray")
         c8.setFill("gray")
    

     elif quitButton0.clicked(pt):
         print("0")
         c0.setFill("red")
         close.active=False
         c1.setFill("gray")
         c2.setFill("gray")
         c3.setFill("gray")
         c4.setFill("gray")
         c5.setFill("gray")
         c6.setFill("gray")
         c7.setFill("gray")
         h.setFill("gray")
    

         quitButton1.active=True
    
         c8.setFill("gray")
    
     elif quitButton.clicked(pt):
         print("2")
         c1.setFill("red")
         quitButton1.active=True
         close.active=False
         c8.setFill("gray")
         c0.setFill("gray")
         c3.setFill("gray")
         c4.setFill("gray")
         c5.setFill("gray")
         c6.setFill("gray")
         c7.setFill("gray")
         h.setFill("gray")
    
    

     elif quitButton1.clicked(pt):
         print("1")
         h.setFill("red")
         quitButton1.active=True
         but.active=False
         close.active = False
         c8.setFill("gray")
         c0.setFill("gray")
         c1.setFill("gray")
         c2.setFill("gray")
         c3.setFill("gray")
         c4.setFill("gray")
         c5.setFill("gray")
         c6.setFill("gray")
         c7.setFill("gray")
    
     elif quitButton2.clicked(pt):
         quitButton.active=True
         print("3")
         c2.setFill("red")
         quitButton1.active=True
         close.active=False
         c8.setFill("gray")
         c1.setFill("gray")
         c0.setFill("gray")
         c3.setFill("gray")
         c4.setFill("gray")
         c5.setFill("gray")
         c6.setFill("gray")
         c7.setFill("gray")
         h.setFill("gray")

     elif quitButton3.clicked(pt):
         quitButton3.active = True
         print("4")
         c3.setFill("red")
         quitButton1.active=True
         close.active=False
         c8.setFill("gray")
         c0.setFill("gray")
         c1.setFill("gray")
         c2.setFill("gray")
         c4.setFill("gray")
         c5.setFill("gray")
         c6.setFill("gray")
         c7.setFill("gray")
         h.setFill("gray")

     elif quitButton4.clicked(pt):
         quitButton4.active = True
         print("5")
         c4.setFill("red")
         close.active=False
         c8.setFill("gray")
         c0.setFill("gray")
         c1.setFill("gray")
         c2.setFill("gray")
         c3.setFill("gray")
         c5.setFill("gray")
         c6.setFill("gray")
         c7.setFill("gray")
         h.setFill("gray")
         close.active=False

         quitButton1.active=True
     elif quitButton5.clicked(pt):
         quitButton5.active = True
         print("6")
         c5.setFill("red")
         close.active=False
         c8.setFill("gray")
         c0.setFill("gray")
         c1.setFill("gray")
         c2.setFill("gray")
         c3.setFill("gray")
         c4.setFill("gray")
         c6.setFill("gray")
         c7.setFill("gray")
         h.setFill("gray")

         quitButton1.active=True
     elif quitButton6.clicked(pt):
         quitButton6.active = True
         print("7")
         c6.setFill("red")
         close.active=False
         quitButton1.active=True
         c8.setFill("gray")
         c0.setFill("gray")
         c1.setFill("gray")
         c2.setFill("gray")
         c3.setFill("gray")
         c4.setFill("gray")
         c5.setFill("gray")
         c7.setFill("gray")
         h.setFill("gray")

     elif quitButton7.clicked(pt):
         quitButton7.active = True
         print("8")
         c7.setFill("red")
         quitButton1.active=True
         close.active=False
         c8.setFill("gray")
         c0.setFill("gray")
         c1.setFill("gray")
         c2.setFill("gray")
         c3.setFill("gray")
         c4.setFill("gray")
         c5.setFill("gray")
         c6.setFill("gray")
         h.setFill("gray")

 
     pt = win.getMouse()

 win.close()
```

Now All what I had to do to close the window if the user click 9-1-1, is that creating another button that is not activated until user clicks immediately after 9>1 then that will activate another button, if you click that button, window will be close, so I made it as if I was making a quit button that won't be activated until user play the game, I know the code look pretty much miss, but it works, you need to analyze my code to understand it, but I am giving you the idea here, now I am done with "if user clicks 9-1-1 window closes", the other thing, is that if user for example clicks the button number "9"  the button color will change from "gray" to "red" and if followed by another click in another button, the button number 9 will from "red" color "gray" color which is the main color for my buttons, the way I did that in while loop here is an example " if user click in button 1, button1 will turn red, if user clicks another button, in if statement, in included that

```
 if button 1.clicked(pt): 
           button1.setFill("red")
           button2.setFill("gray")
      elif button2.clicked(pt):
           button2.setFill("red")
           button1.setFill("gray") # that way if you click button 1, button 1 will turn red, when you click button 2, button 2 will turn red, and will turn button 1 to gray color
```